# Create ENUM in POSTGRESQL using Codeigniter Migrations and DBFORGE

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, enums

I want to create a table with ENUM field in postgres database.

Normally, when we create enum in postgresql we name the enum and the column we want to set the enum we , choose that enum name. But how do I do this in Codeigniter ?

Below is my code:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Migration_Admin_Locations extends CI_Migration {

        public function up()
        {

                $this->dbforge->add_field(array(
                        'id' => array(
                                'type' => 'INT',
                                'null' => FALSE,
                                'auto_increment'=>TRUE,
                                'constraint' => 11,
                        ),
                        'location_name' => array(
                                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                                 'constraint' => 50,
                                 'null' => TRUE,
                        ),
                        'tenant_id' => array(
                                'type' => 'INT',
                                'null' => TRUE,
                        ),
                        'description' => array(
                                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                                 'constraint' => 128,
                                 'null' => TRUE,
                        ),
                        'is_default' => array(
                                'type' => 'ENUM("a","b","c")',
                                'default' => "a",
                                'null' => TRUE,
                        ),
                ));

            $this->dbforge->add_key('id');
            $this->dbforge->create_table('admin_locations');
            $query = $this->db->get('admin_locations');
            $res=$query->num_rows();

             if($res==0)
             {
                $data = array(
                        'id'=>"1",
                        'location_name'=>"default site",
                        'tenant_id'=>"1",
                        'description'=>"This is default site for portal",
                        'is_default'=>"a",
                     );
                $this->db->insert('admin_locations', $data); 
            }

        }
        public function down()
        {
          $this->dbforge->drop_table('admin_locations');
        }
}
```

But this triggers an error  :

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning
>
> Message: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: type "enum" does not exist
>   LINE 6: "is_default" ENUM("a","b","c") DEFAULT 'no' NULL ^
>
> Filename: postgre/postgre_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 242
>
> Backtrace:

Comment: I don't know CI, but normally, in PostgreSQL you must first create your enum type and then use it as field type - see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html.

Comment: @Furgas yes i know that, i was just wondering if CI had any abilites to do that on my behalf, if not then the DB Forge library is usless

Comment: I am not sure why this is voted down ! If you have an answer give it instead of just voting down the question

Comment: I guess you will first have to use pure SQL to create the enum type (probably with $this->db->query(...)) and then you can use its name in `add_field` type.

Comment: Yes i belive so, I would import the SQL or CI Query Builder  for creating enum types and then will do the CI migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you must first create your enum type and then use it as field type. See PostgreSQL enumerated type [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html) for reference.

I don't know CI much, but I see that [Database Forge class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/forge.html) has no support for creating enum types so you will have to first create it using pure SQL or some CI SQL builder, and then probably you will be able to use that enum type name in `add_field` method.

Comment: I don't know PostgreSQL but I know CI, in CI3 you can add enum field with dbforge, I am using it (v3.1.11) with MySQL. P.S. I have been trying to use it with SQlite too but nope SQlite seems not to have enum type.

Comment: @AdemTepe Yeah, in MySQL you can define ENUM type for specific table column on the fly. In PostgreSQL you must first create enum type and then you can reference it as column type in column definition (or multiple columns).

Answer (score -1):

in enum you cannot pass null data ... this is sql error... change `is_default` array

```
'null' => TRUE,
```

to

```
'null' => FALSE,
```

Comment: set is null for default  ... if it dose not catch value ... then the default value take place ... if you dose not set default value ... then it become null ... you cannot upload enum field as null ...